# How can I detect when new entries are made in GWT-LOG through Selenium?

Tags: java, gwt, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a website that uses the Google Web Toolkit (GWT). In particular, the website pops-up the GWT-LOG window, which displays all the background activity that's taking place on the site.

I'm writing some Selenium tests and I need to be able to access the entries in the GWT-LOG.

Right now, I've managed to write code that can take a chunk of GWT-LOG by using XPaths -- I'm using a **previous** and **current** "pointer" to keep track of where I last left off within the GWT-LOG window.

```
/**
 * Adds each GWT-LOG entry (one line) between "prevXPC" and "curXPC" into an
 * ArrayList<String> -- one line per ArrayList index.
 */
public void parseString(ArrayList<String> list) {
    // Total count of gwt-log entries
    int curXPC = driver.findElements(By.xpath(gwtXPath)).size();

    // Empty the ArrayList
    list.clear();

    // Add elements to the ArrayList between pXPC and cXPC counts
    for (int i = prevXPC; i <= curXPC; i++) {
        String logEntryXPath = "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/div[" + i + "]";
        String newEntry = driver.findElement(By.xpath(logEntryXPath)).getText();
        list.add(newEntry);
    }

    prevXPC = (curXPC + 1); // Set the previous XPath count to the current one.
}
```

This code works fine when I know that all the log entries have shown up in the GWT-LOG window. But, when I perform an action where some entries show up and then after a few seconds more entries show up, such as when the site is waiting for server information, my code isn't very effective.

Is there any way to constantly keep an "eye" on the GWT-LOG entries and alert me, or save new GWT-LOG entries to an `ArrayList<String>` like I did before, using Selenium?

Otherwise, I'm going to have to put Waits in my tests to counter this issue. This wouldn't be the most ideal option since the length of the Wait can either be too much or too little.

Comment: Would this be easier using "Remote Logging" feature in GWT? https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging#Remote_Logging

Comment: Would I need access to the GWT code? Because I don't have access to it on this site.

Comment: Yes my suggestion would mean change in GWT code/compilation.